# VBA Excel combine string and turn into chart object

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a function that cycles through a row of data, assign each cell to a variable before using these variables in a function to copy paste a graph or range.

The issue I'm having is building the the Chart path as a combination of string variables, I can create the chart path as a string from my wb,sheet and chartName string variables, but I'm struggling to then make this into a chart object.

Running the below code with `Dim cht as Chart` I get the error (1)

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or with black variable not set"

when I Dim `cht as String` I get the error (2)

> "Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch"

this is my code - I have commented error position

```
Sub RollingCode()

    Dim height As Double
    Dim weight As Double
    Dim gender As String
    Dim newWeight As Double
    Dim ImageType As String
    Dim wB As String
    Dim sH As String
    Dim NameRange As String
    Dim Sld As Integer
    Dim DataTyp As Integer
    Dim TopPos As Integer
    Dim LeftPos As Integer
    Dim WidthPos As Integer
    Dim HeightPos As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As String 'WHEN CHART ERROR 1, WHEN STRING ERROR 2

    'Open powerpoint
    'Call Module2.OpenPowerpoint


    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        ImageType = Range("A" & i).Value
        wB = Range("B" & i).Value
        sH = Range("C" & i).Value
        NameRange = Range("D" & i).Value
        Sld = Range("E" & i).Value
        DataTyp = Range("F" & i).Value
        TopPos = Range("G" & i).Value
        LeftPos = Range("H" & i).Value
        WidthPos = Range("I" & i).Value
        HeightPos = Range("J" & i).Value

        If wB = "Active" Then
            Select Case ImageType

                   Case "chart", "Chart"

                        cht = "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" & sH & ").ChartObjects(" & NameRange & ").Chart" 'ERROR 1 HERE

                        'MsgBox cht
                        CopyPasteChartFull Sld, cht, LeftPos, TopPos, WidthPos, HeightPos 'ERROR 2 HERE

                   Case "Range", "range"
                        MsgBox "Range"
                   Case Else
                        MsgBox "Incorrect"
                   End Select

        Else
            Select Case ImageType

             'Irrelevant code here

            End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

To summarise, how can I turn a string to a chart object, where wb = active, sh = "Forecast", and NameRange = "Chart 1"

Thanks

Comment: no need for the " and it will be `set cht=`

Comment: Is `CopyPasteChartFull` a UDF? If so, where is the code for it?

Comment: If it was declared as `Dim cht As Chart` it should be something like `Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sH).ChartObjects(NameRange).Chart`

Comment: @dwirony CopyPasteChartFull is a function (its quite long so didnt want to post) where cht is declared as a chart

Comment: @PEH that solution seems to give me a Run-time error '9': subscript out of range at my set cht =

Comment: @TisButaScratch that means that either the sheet or the chartobject does not exist. Debug your code and check the values in `sH` and `NameRange` by going through step by step using F8.

Comment: Just got it working! it was because i was actually passing "Forecast" and not Forecast, hence it couldnt find the sheet. Thankyou everyone for your help

Comment: What's the point of `Case "chart", "Chart"`? Write `Option Compare Text` at the declaration section (the top of the module) - and you can just write `Case "chart"`.

Comment: @JohnyL thanks for the knowledge nugget, I didnt know you could do that!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: @JohnyL Alternatively, use `Select Case LCase$(ImageType)`.